# php mcrypt_encrypt encryption mismatch with android AES-128 encryption

Tags: php, android, encryption, cryptography

I need encryption in all api request and response I am using the following code. But encrypted value of php code is not matching with the one generated by android.

```
function encrypt($input,$key) {
     $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); 
     $input = $this->pkcs5_pad($input, $size); 
     $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, ''); 
     $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND); 
     mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key); 
     $data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input); 
     mcrypt_generic_deinit($td); 
     mcrypt_module_close($td); 
     $data = base64_encode($data); 
     return $data; 
}

function aesdecrypt($sStr,$sKey){
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, ''); 
     $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND); 
    $decrypted= mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        $sKey, 
        base64_decode($sStr), 
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC
    );
    $dec_s = strlen($decrypted); 
    $padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s-1]); 
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);
    return $decrypted;
}
```

android code (for encrypt and decrypt) :

```
public static String encode(String password, String text)
        throws NoPassGivenException, NoTextGivenException {
    /*if (password.length() == 0 || password == null) {
        throw new NoPassGivenException("Please give Password");
    }

    if (text.length() == 0 || text == null) {
        throw new NoTextGivenException("Please give text");
    }*/

    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = getKey(password);
        byte[] clearText = text.getBytes("UTF8");

        //IMPORTANT TO GET SAME RESULTS ON iOS and ANDROID
        final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        Arrays.fill(iv, (byte) 0x00);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        //System.out.println(iv);
        // Cipher is not thread safe
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

        String encrypedValue = new Base64().encodeAsString(
                cipher.doFinal(clearText));

        //Log.d(TAG, "Encrypted: " + text + " -> " + encrypedValue);
        return encrypedValue;

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
public static String decode(String password, String text)
        throws NoPassGivenException, NoTextGivenException {

    /*if (password.length() == 0 || password == null) {
        throw new NoPassGivenException("Please give Password");
    }

    if (text.length() == 0 || text == null) {
        throw new NoTextGivenException("Please give text");
    }*/

    try {
        SecretKey key = getKey(password);

        //IMPORTANT TO GET SAME RESULTS ON iOS and ANDROID
        final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        Arrays.fill(iv, (byte) 0x00);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        //System.out.println(iv);
        byte[] encrypedPwdBytes = new Base64().decodeBase64(text);
        // cipher is not thread safe
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] decrypedValueBytes = (cipher.doFinal(encrypedPwdBytes));

        String decrypedValue = new String(decrypedValueBytes);

       // BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(decrypedValue);
        //Log.d(TAG, "Decrypted: " + text + " -> " + decrypedValue);
       // String data =  Long.toString(bd.longValue());
        return decrypedValue;

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using secured connections (https)?

Comment: You're using a random IV which is desirable. If you want to check for compatibility, you need to encrypt in one, decrypt in the other and check whether you got the original plaintext back. Then you do that again in the other direction.

Comment: Note that the use of PHP and Android could indicate transport security. Just CBC is not enough to provide transport security - it may not even provide confidentiality because of padding oracle attacks. Kudos for using a random IV, AES and PKCS#7 compatible padding though.

Answer (score 2):

Ciphertext is supposed to be indistinguishable from random. That is the main reason for a unique or - in case of CBC mode - random IV. If you would use a static IV (and the same key) you would get the same (first blocks of) ciphertext for the same (first blocks of) plaintext. In other words, you would be leaking information to an attacker.

That's why you *should* use a random IV, which you can safely store together with the ciphertext. Encryption can best be tested by decryption. Signature generation can likewise best be tested with signature verification. If you manage to generate the same CBC ciphertext twice then this is an indication that something is wrong - not that something is right.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved this problem it was because of mismatching IV values.